# MongoDB and SpEL Expressions in @Document annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, spring-el

I am trying to use the SpEL to load the same Document into different collections based on some rules that i have defined.

So to start with what i have:

-first of all the document:

```
@Document(collection = "#{@mySpecialProvider.getTargetCollectionName()}")
public class MongoDocument {
// some random fields go in
}
```

-second i have the provider bean that should provide the collection name:

```
@Component("mySpecialProvider")
public class MySpecialProvider {

public String getTargetCollectionName() {
// Thread local magic goes in bellow
    String targetCollectionName = (String) RequestLocalContext.getFromLocalContext("targetCollectionName");
    if (targetCollectionName == null) {
        targetCollectionName = "defaultCollection";
    }
    return targetCollectionName;
 }
}
```

The problem is that when i try to insert a document into a specific collection that should be generated by the provider i get the following stacktrace:

**org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1057E:(pos 1): No bean resolver registered in the context to resolve access to bean 'mySpecialProvider'**

I also tried making the spring component **ApplicationContextAware** but still no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As i promised i am returning with an answer to my question.
To have it working you need to have the following settings for the **mongoTemplate** bean in the application context XML file:

```
<mongo:db-factory dbname="${myDatabaseName.from.properties.file}" mongo-ref="mongo"/>
<bean id="mongoMappingContext" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext"/>   
<bean id="mappingMongoConverter" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter" c:mongoDbFactory-ref="mongoDbFactory"
            c:mappingContext-ref="mongoMappingContext"/>
<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate"
            c:mongoDbFactory-ref="mongoDbFactory" c:mongoConverter-ref="mappingMongoConverter"/>
```

And with the settings above and the solution i suggested in my question works. You can use the same domain object and store it into multiple collections based on settings of your choosing.

**EDIT:**

Since someone asked for it in a related question, i will also update here the logic for the ThreadLocal context:

Make a **RequestLocalContext** class that wraps over the following implementation:

```
private static final ThreadLocal<Map> CONTEXT = new ThreadLocal<Map>() {
        protected Map initialValue() {
            Map localMap = new HashMap();
            localMap.put(LocalContextKeys.CONVERSATION_CONTEXT, new HashMap());
            return localMap;
        };
    };

public static void putInLocalContext(Object key, Object value) {
    Map localMap = CONTEXT.get();
    localMap.put(key, value);
}

 public static Object getFromLocalContext(Object key) {
    Map localMap = CONTEXT.get();
    return localMap.get(key);
}
```

Where **LocalContextKeys** is an enum containing the keys allowed in the the **ThreadLocal** context **Map**. Note that the keys are user defined so feel free to put in there whatever you may need.

Comment: Your threadlocal code also was very helpful, thanks for all the insights

Answer (score 1):

You could use mongo template's method instead: save(Object objectToSave, String collectionName).

Comment: i know about that but i wanted a more generic solution. a colleague of mine found it so i will post the answer tomorrow morning