# Spring Data MongoDB Repository with custom collection name

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, repository

I am using Spring Data for MongoDB and I need to be able to configure collection at runtime.

My repository is defined as:

```
@Repository
public interface EventDataRepository extends MongoRepository<EventData, String> {
}
```

I tried this silly example:

```
@Document(collection = "${mongo.event.collection}")
public class EventData implements Serializable {
```

but mongo.event.collection did not resolve to a name as it does with a @Value annotation.

A bit more debugging and searching and I tried the following:
    @Document(collection = "#{${mongo.event.collection}}")

This produced an exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1041E:(pos 1): After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'lcurly({)'
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.doParseExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:129)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser.doParseExpression(SpelExpressionParser.java:60)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser.doParseExpression(SpelExpressionParser.java:32)
    at org.springframework.expression.common.TemplateAwareExpressionParser.parseExpressions(TemplateAwareExpressionParser.java:154)
    at org.springframework.expression.common.TemplateAwareExpressionParser.parseTemplate(TemplateAwareExpressionParser.java:85)
```

Perhaps I just don't know how to quite use SPel to access values from Spring's Property Configurer.

When stepping through the code, I see that there is a way to specify collection name or even expressions, however, I am not sure which annotation should be used for this purpose or how to do it.

Thanks.
-AP_

Comment: Maybe that's your problem? https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1043 `...` which version of spring-data-mongodb are you using?

Comment: It could be (I am using 1.7.0-RELEASE), however, the issue you mentioned deals with expressions in queries between multiple invocations.  However, you did clue me that it has to be a proper SPEL expression, so I changed it.  See updated question.

Answer (score 6):

You can solve this problem by just using SPeL:

```
@Document(collection = "#{environment.getProperty('mongo.event.collection')}")
public class EventData implements Serializable {
    ...
}
```

**Update Spring 5.x:**

Since Spring 5.x or so you need an additional @ before *environment*:

```
@Document(collection = "#{@environment.getProperty('mongo.event.collection')}")
public class EventData implements Serializable {
    ...
}
```

Docs:

- [SpEL: 4.2 Expressions in Bean Definitions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.4/reference/html/core.html#expressions-beandef)
- [SpEL: 4.3.12 Bean References](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.4/reference/html/core.html#expressions-bean-references)
- [PropertyResolver::getProperty](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.4/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/PropertyResolver.html#getProperty-java.lang.String-)

Comment: You are a life saver. I know comments should not be used to Thank. But this answered a lot of my problems. 
Would you be kind enough to include the reference from Spring Documentation.

Comment: I added some Docs which describe all the parts which are used in the example code. Does this help you?

Comment: For those who have trouble with the chapter links not working in Spring Docs. Refer Chapter 4

Comment: I added the chapter numbers to the href label.

Answer (score 5):

So, at the end, here is a work around that did the trick.  I guess I really don't know how to access data from Spring Properties Configurer using the SPeL expressions.

In my @Configuration class:

```
@Value("${mongo.event.collection}")
private String
    mongoEventCollectionName;

@Bean
public String mongoEventCollectionName() {
    return
        mongoEventCollectionName;
}
```

On my Document:

```
@Document(collection = "#{mongoEventCollectionName}")
```

This, appears to work and properly pick up the name configured in my .properties file, however, I am still not sure why I could not just access the value with $ as I do in the @Value annotation.

Comment: This answer helped me in some directions, but I keep getting an error "Property or field 'mongoEventCollectionName' cannot be found on null". the injection into the bean seems to work fine, but not the one into `@Document`

Comment: I got it working thanks to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21045404/2375586): set the ApplicationContext into the MongoMappingContext.

Answer (score 3):

define your entity class like

```
@Document(collection = "${EventDataRepository.getCollectionName()}")
public class EventData implements Serializable {
```

Define a custom repository interface with getter and setter methods for "collectionName"

```
public interface EventDataRepositoryCustom {

    String getCollectionName();

    void setCollectionName(String collectionName);
}
```

provide implementation class for custom repository with "collectionName" implementation

```
public class EventDataRepositoryImpl implements EventDataRepositoryCustom{

    private static String collectionName = "myCollection";

    @Override
    public String getCollectionName() {
        return collectionName;
    }

    @Override
    public void setCollectionName(String collectionName) {
        this.collectionName = collectionName;
    }
}
```

Add `EventDataRepositoryImpl` to the extends list of your repository interface in this it would look like

```
@Repository
public interface EventDataRepository extends MongoRepository<EventData, String>, EventDataRepositoryImpl  {
}
```

Now in your Service class where you are using the `MongoRepository` set the collection name, it would look like

```
@Autowired
EventDataRepository  repository ;

repository.setCollectionName("collectionName");
```

Answer (score 0):

Entity Class

```
@Document    // remove the parameters from here


public class EscalationCase 
{

}
```

Configuration class

```
public class MongoDBConfiguration {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MongoDBConfiguration.class);

    @Value("${sfdc.mongodb.collection}") //taking collection name from properties file 
    private String collectionName;

    @Bean

    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate(MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory, MongoMappingContext context) {

        MappingMongoConverter converter = new MappingMongoConverter(new DefaultDbRefResolver(mongoDbFactory), context);
        converter.setTypeMapper(new DefaultMongoTypeMapper(null));
        MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory, converter);
        if (!mongoTemplate.collectionExists(collectionName)) {
            mongoTemplate.createCollection(collectionName);  // adding the collection name here
        }
        return mongoTemplate;

    }
}
```