# Can I switch between two collections under same DB in java spring-boot application?

Tags: database, mongodb, spring-boot, collections, spring-mongodb

I have mongodb related code in my java application and can I switch between two collections under same db in java code ?

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Document(collection = "collectionA")
@QueryEntity
public class RepreCase {
```

I want to have a different collection here instead of this say **collectionB**   `@Document(collection = "collectionA")` and comeback to the same `collectionA`, by switching between the two collections A & B under same DB

Can I do like this ? `@Document(collection = "collectionA, collectionB")`

Is it achievable & How ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29597482/spring-data-mongodb-repository-with-custom-collection-name) should help

Define your entity class like

```
@Document(collection = "${EventDataRepository.getCollectionName()}")
public class EventData implements Serializable {
```

Define a custom repository interface with getter and setter methods for "collectionName"

```
public interface EventDataRepositoryCustom {

    String getCollectionName();

    void setCollectionName(String collectionName);
}
```

Provide implementation class for custom repository with "collectionName" implementation

```
public class EventDataRepositoryImpl implements EventDataRepositoryCustom{

    private static String collectionName = "myCollection";

    @Override
    public String getCollectionName() {
        return collectionName;
    }

    @Override
    public void setCollectionName(String collectionName) {
        this.collectionName = collectionName;
    }
}
```

Add EventDataRepositoryImpl to the extends list of your repository interface in this it would look like

```
@Repository
public interface EventDataRepository extends MongoRepository<EventData, String>, EventDataRepositoryImpl  {
}
```

Now in your Service class where you are using the MongoRepository set the collection name, it would look like

```
@Autowired
EventDataRepository  repository ;

repository.setCollectionName("collectionName");
```