# Cannot resolve bean in SpEL for Spring Data MongoDB collection name

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-data-mongodb, spring-el

I am trying to customize the collection name where an entity class is saved into and indexed, using Spring Data MongoDB and Spring Batch. The class is declared as follows:

```
@Document
@CompoundIndex(name = "unique_source", def = "{'fid': 1, 'sid': 1}", unique = true, background = true)
public class VariantSource {
    ...
}
```

And the item writer:

```
public class VariantSourceMongoWriter extends MongoItemWriter<VariantSource> {

    public VariantSourceEntityMongoWriter(MongoOperations mongoOperations, String collectionName) {
        setTemplate(mongoOperations);
        setCollection(collectionName);
    }
}
```

Saving works fine: the objects are written into the collection provided as argument. The problem is that the indexes are created in the default collection, named after the class name (`variantSource`).

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29597482/spring-data-mongodb-repository-with-custom-collection-name) and [this](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-525), I created the following:

```
public class MongoCollections {

    public String getCollectionFilesName() {
        return "my_custom_collection_name"; // TODO Dynamic value
    }
}


@Configuration
public class MongoCollectionsConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MongoCollections mongoCollections() {
        return new MongoCollections(); 
    }


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MongoCollectionsConfiguration.class})
public class VariantSourceMongoWriterTest {

    @Autowired
    private MongoCollections mongoCollections;

}
```

I have checked the instance is correctly autowired into the unit tests, but I can't make it work with SpEL.

After changing the `@Document` annotation to look like this:

```
@Document(collection = "#{@mongoCollections.getCollectionFilesName()}")
```

the following exception is thrown:

> org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1057E:(pos 1): No bean resolver registered in the context to resolve access to bean 'mongoCollections'

And if I use this:

```
@Document(collection = "#{mongoCollections.getCollectionFilesName()}")
```

the exception is this one:

> org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E:(pos 0): Property or field 'mongoCollections' cannot be found on null

Finally, the following creates a collection with the name as specified, symbols included:

```
@Document(collection = "@mongoCollections.getCollectionFilesName()")
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip using `@mongoCollections.getCollectionFilesName()`, that worked for me as well! Does anyone know why that works? Is that even valid SpEL?

Comment: @JanGassen `@mongoCollections.getCollectionFilesName()` didn't work for me, it ended up creating a collection with name `@mongoCollections.getCollectionFilesName()` (non-dynamic). I am using Spring Data 2.2.10.

Answer (score 5):

As pointed by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21045404/2375586), to fix the injection:

```
@Document(collection = "#{mongoCollections.getCollectionFilesName()}")
```

> SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E:(pos 0): Property or field 'mongoCollections' cannot be found on null

(or a direct method bean: `@Document(collection = "#{getCollectionFilesName}")`), try setting the ApplicationContext into the MongoMappingContext (which is used to instantiate the MongoConverter, and later the MongoTemplate):

```
@Bean
public MongoMappingContext MongoMappingContext() {
    MongoMappingContext mappingContext = new MongoMappingContext();
    mappingContext.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    return mappingContext;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your bean mongoCollections is registered in the application context, 
and also correct the SpEL expression as below.

@Document(collection = "#{@mongoCollections.getCollectionFilesName()}")

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get my `@Document` tag to access a bean by simply changing my `MongoTemplate` configuration file.

Previously, I had it set up like this:

```java
@Configuration
public class MongoTemplateConfiguration {

    ...

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() {
        ...
        return new MongoTemplate(...);
    }
}
```

Changing it to follow [this (3.2 Java Configuration)](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-tutorial#2-java-configuration) format was all I needed in order to remove the "bean resolver" error:

```java
@Configuration
public class MongoTemplateConfiguration extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration {

    ...

    @Override
    @Bean
    public com.mongodb.client.MongoClient mongoClient() {
        MongoClientSettings settings = ...;
        return MongoClients.create(settings);
    }
}
```